# When the code goes in the print_city function, the variable "code_search" reset to 0

Tags: c++, function, void

[image]

Here's where my code freak out Ive tried to initialize in the main, in the search but nothing works, thank you in advance, and i have to kept the two functions I can't put them in the same one! so code_search is at 1 but when it goes to the print_city it goes back at 0.

Comment: Please post code as text. Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just paste the code here as text, instead of creating an image of the code and fiddling around with png and jpeg files?

Comment: `code_search` is passed by value, so assigning to it in search_city does nothing. You want to return a value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SuperStorme said, you are passing `code_search` by value. Try to pass it by reference:

```
void search_city(City cities_array[], const int MAX_Cities, int & code_search){...}
```

Passing by value, you are changing only the local variable `code_search` in the function scope.

Comment: Passing by reference probably isn't the best solution here because it changes the nature of what `code_search` stores from a search to to an index. A better approach would be to `return i;` when the code is found.